# Windows 10 Review Settings

Tags: windows

My screen is blocked by the Windows 10 "Review Settings" message wanting to place update on my computer.  Cannot clear the screen without turning off.  But when turning on again the same message appears.  No other buttons work, including "Escape".
Is it safe to proceed by hitting "Review Settings" button or is this a scam?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: If you cannot provide a screenshot, perhaps provide a photo. All in all it sounds like you received the Windows 10 Creators Update. It’s now being delivered to most (all?) PCs.

Comment: Does Ctrl/Shift/Esc work? Should bring up Task Manager without any intervening screen.

Comment: A screen shot would be nice but I would not trust it if it was not familiar

Comment: Updates automatically install on W10 so I doubt that the pop-up you see is legit. Scan that system with anti-spyware/ad-ware.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a scam, just Microsoft trying to install the
[Windows 10 Creators Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028685/windows-get-the-windows-10-creators-update).

The window you are getting should look like this :

[image]

And clicking on Review settings should lead to the following screen :

[image]

Set your preferences and let Windows upgrade your computer.

**Important remark**: If you do not have full backups of the computer,
make every effort to create these backups before updating the computer.
If the above dialog blocks you from doing that, try to boot in Safe mode
(see [this link](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10)).